# can getResource search at multiple places?

Tags: java, getresource

can getResource check existence of file in multiple locations?
I have a file named db.properties. Below is what is written in my java file. I understand that adding / before file name would look at absolulte path.

```
String filename = "/db.properties"; 
URL url = getClass().getResource(filename);
    System.out.println(url.getPath());
```

The above code printed - /loc1/loc2/WEB-INF/classes/db.properties
and this is fine.

then I removed db.properties from above location and moved it to - /loc1/config/db.properties and to my surprise it was able to find file at the above location and printed - /loc1/config/db.properties

I am confused how getResource is looking for a file at multiple locations?

Comment: All getResource\* methods search the entire classpath.

Comment: Yes, classpath is /loc1/loc2/WEB-INF/classes/* and not /loc1/config/*